# Pointing the form_tag to the Update Action of the Controller

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, routes, nested-routes

I have this in my view; I made the "new" and "edit" views similar with only the following snippet which dictates if the form is a patch or a post.

```
<% @selected_holiday[:id].present? ? (current_method = :patch) : (current_method = :post) %>
<%=
    form_tag( {method: current_method},
              class: 'create_form',
              id: "new_holiday_form",
              :"data-parsley-validate" => "" ) do
%>
```

My routes contains:

```
                  human_resources_settings_holidays GET      /human_resources/settings/holidays(.:format)                         human_resources/settings/holidays#index
                                                      POST     /human_resources/settings/holidays(.:format)                         human_resources/settings/holidays#create
                 new_human_resources_settings_holiday GET      /human_resources/settings/holidays/new(.:format)                     human_resources/settings/holidays#new
                edit_human_resources_settings_holiday GET      /human_resources/settings/holidays/:id/edit(.:format)                human_resources/settings/holidays#edit
                     human_resources_settings_holiday GET      /human_resources/settings/holidays/:id(.:format)                     human_resources/settings/holidays#show
                                                      PATCH    /human_resources/settings/holidays/:id(.:format)                     human_resources/settings/holidays#update
                                                      PUT      /human_resources/settings/holidays/:id(.:format)                     human_resources/settings/holidays#update
```

Yet from

```
http://localhost:3000/human_resources/settings/holidays/7d525fe6-b1e7-11e5-b6e8-00ff6a8ddd39/edit
```

I get:

```
http://localhost:3000/human_resources/settings/holidays/7d525fe6-b1e7-11e5-b6e8-00ff6a8ddd39/edit?method=patch
```

and therefore:

```
The action '7d525fe6-b1e7-11e5-b6e8-00ff6a8ddd39' could not be found for HumanResources::Settings::HolidaysController
```

How do I not hit the edit path and go through the PATCH?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<% @selected_holiday[:id].present? ? (current_method = :patch) : (current_method = :post) %>
<%=
    form_tag(human_resources_settings_holiday_path, method: current_method,
              class: 'create_form',
              id: "new_holiday_form",
              :"data-parsley-validate" => "" ) do
%>
```

The first argument in your example make is a part of the URL params. You can also pass `nil` as the first argument if you want to specify current page as `action`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag

You probably want to switch the form action path accordingly as well

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good time to refactor so that you don't have to do this checking at all. The rails form_for :resource helper allows you have pass in the resource, in this case @selected_holiday, and it will create the appropriate methods/actions.

[Rails form_for documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html)